# How to get selected text on click of an element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div with `[contenteditable=true]` attribute. When I select some text and click a button, I want to get the selected text. I did the following:

```
$(".btn").click(function (){
   alert(window.getSelection());
});
```

The above code does not alert anything. If I change the `.btn` element to an `img` element, the alert outputs the selected text. What can I do to get selected text on click of any element

Thid is my html code:

```
<li class="btn">Selection </li>
<div contenteditable="true">Some text here</div>
```

Comment: Probably it is a focus problem. The button gets the focus and the selection is lost.

Comment: can you also share your html

Comment: Make sure the selection doesn't go out of focus and  try `toString()` ?

Comment: There is no error. With any element apart from img the selected text is not being displayed

Comment: How do I stop the selection from going out of focus

Comment: works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/xspob3ko/  please can u you share your html and also if there is your css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select your required text and click the button, as Ramon & adeneo explains in his comment, the focus is lost. Button command is executed at `mouseup`at which point the selection is cleared. As far as I understand, the reason why your code works with an image because unlike a button the image command is executed at `mousedown`.

My suggestion would be to try an `.on('mousedown', ...)` command instead of a simple click command.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script language=javascript>
    function getSelText()  {
        var txt = '';
        if (window.getSelection) {
            txt = window.getSelection();
        }
        else if (document.getSelectiion) {
            txt = document.getSelection();
        }
        else if (document.selection) {
           txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }
        else return;
        alert(txt)
     }


      window.document.onmousedown = function() {
        getSelText()
     }
     </script>
```